# Take last database post in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I am teaching myself rails (coming from PHP for web apps) and I can't find any good docs to help me. But I was wondering how would you tell your method to take the last post(controller is post) in the database? I tried Post.find(:last) but that did nothing sadly. Anyone know?

Comment: def index
 @post = Post.find(:last)
 respond_to do |format|
  format.html
 end
end
My code is something like this. (It's on my netbook so I kinda copied it) Also, there are posts in the DB.

Comment: Thanks, I got it after I deleted and started over. I didn't use a scaffold this time and I believe that the scaffold did something (along with my ignorance) to mess it up. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

Try `Post.last`. It's shorter.

But as inkdeep said, be sure you have posts in the DB to begin with. Try this:

```
Post.create :title => "Boring Title", :body => "Blah Blah Blah"
```

(assuming you have title and body columns)

`create` does a one-step object instantiation and save (be warned--`Post.new` doesn't save anything to the DB, you need to explicitly `.save`)

Answer (score 0):

[guide.rubyonrails](http://guides.rubyonrails.com)

There's a few links to start you off.

Are you sure there are posts saved to the database? That method should work if you have a Post model (the model name should be singular).

Answer (score 0):

You have two common solutions depending on your needs:

```
Post.find(:first,:order=>'id desc') #It's slow in MySQL
Post.find(:first,:order=>:created_at) #You have to add the 'created_at' field but it gets updated 'automagically'
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe the following should do the trick assuming you have a Post model object:

```
Post.find(:all).last
```

I'm learning Rails too and I'm following the book [Simply Rails 2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0980455200).  These other two books are also recommended for Rails dev:

1. [Agile Web Development with Rails](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356166)
2. [Rails for PHP Developers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356042)

Try to find the above in your local public libraries, they might have it.  Otherwise, the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/) does a good job.

Comment: Careful with that statement as it loads *all* Posts from the DB and then returns the last one. "Post.last" is the proper call.